# Allow Sign In without email confirmation in ASP.Net Core MVC Identity (NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have registered a new user in my ASP.Net Core MVC Identity and haven't confirmed its email yet. When the value of `EmailConfirmed` column in the `AspNetUsers` database table is "False", I cannot Sign In.

When I changed the `EmailConfirmed` column's value to "True", I can Sign In.

Is there a way to enable Sign In without email confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

This is an option you can configure when your app starts up.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false);
```

or

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(
    options => 
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    });
```